# SoundCloud API Stream Quality

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I've been working on an iOS app that streams DJ mixes from SoundCloud.  The mixes are roughly 2 hours in length.

I was reading the App Store guidelines and item 9.3 has me a bit concerned:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#media-content

9.3 - Audio streaming content over a cellular network may not use more than 5MB over 5 minutes

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve a low quality stream so I can give users a choice of what quality stream they would like to listen to.

...Or - if there are people with experience with a similar situation - how are you guys addressing this App Store guideline?

Comment: [Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html) says `Provide a 64 Kbps stream. Non-compliant apps may be rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.`.

Comment: The question is pertaining to the SoundCloud API and retrieving a low quality stream from it (or whether or not it's actually necessary to worry about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mp3s SoundCloud delivers in the stream are encoded in 128kbit CBR.

128kbit/s = 0.9375 MB / min (use [google conversion tool](https://www.google.de/search?q=128+kbit+%2Fs+in+MB%2Fmin))

5 minutes of stream = 4.6875 MB (+ a little bit of overhead).

So you're still within the bounds of Apple's requirements with the default streaming quality.